# how to apply ffill() groupby and conditionally on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to fill previous value like `ffill()` conditionally.

For example, if ['day'] columns is 'None', I want to apply ['close'] `ffill()` on `Groupby`.

I attached example as below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','MSFT','MSFT','MSFT','MSFT','MSFT','MSFT'],
                   'day' : [None,'Fri', None, None, 'Mon', 'Thue', None,'Fri', None, None, 'Mon', 'Thue',],
                   'close' : [np.nan, 174.49, np.nan, np.nan, 175.84, np.nan, np.nan, 128.11, np.nan, np.nan, 128.93, np.nan]
                   })

   # df
   # Out[46]: 
   # AAPL  None     NaN
   # AAPL   Fri  174.49
   # AAPL  None     NaN
   # AAPL  None     NaN
   # AAPL   Mon  175.84
   # AAPL  Thue     NaN
   # MSFT  None     NaN
   # MSFT   Fri  128.11
   # MSFT  None     NaN
   # MSFT  None     NaN
   # MSFT   Mon  128.93
   # MSFT  Thue     NaN



# What I wannt
#    name   day   close
#    AAPL  None     NaN
#    AAPL   Fri  174.49
#    AAPL  None  174.49 <- if 'day' is None then wnat to ffill() 
#    AAPL  None  174.49 <- if 'day' is None then wnat to ffill() 
#    AAPL   Mon  175.84
#    AAPL  Thue     NaN
#    MSFT  None     NaN
#    MSFT   Fri  128.11
#    MSFT  None  128.11 <- if 'day' is None then wnat to ffill() 
#    MSFT  None  128.11 <- if 'day' is None then wnat to ffill() 
#    MSFT   Mon  128.93
#    MSFT  Thue     NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward fill the values in `close` per stock then use boolean indexing to update the values where `day` is none

```
m = df['day'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'close'] = df.groupby('name')['close'].ffill()
```

---

```
    name   day   close
0   AAPL  None     NaN
1   AAPL   Fri  174.49
2   AAPL  None  174.49
3   AAPL  None  174.49
4   AAPL   Mon  175.84
5   AAPL  Thue     NaN
6   MSFT  None     NaN
7   MSFT   Fri  128.11
8   MSFT  None  128.11
9   MSFT  None  128.11
10  MSFT   Mon  128.93
11  MSFT  Thue     NaN
```